# How to reload Dropotron data (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am unable to figure out how to reload the `<ul>` and `<li>` after the page was loaded.

I have `<li>` object which changes after getting ajax data and if I try and change the DOM using jQuery it changes but when Dropotron opens it shows only the old data.

Has anyone knows how to solve it ?

(I even tried to reload the whole navigation element  `$('#nav > ul').dropotron({});` but it adds another dropotron menu over it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a workaround of my issue,
At the initialization of the navigation object I have changed the two parameters:
**detach, cloneOnDetach** to false
to false and I was able to change them later in code

I would like to understand what those two parameters mean and what is the disadvantage of changing them to **false**

```js
$('#nav > ul').dropotron({
    mode: 'fade',
    speed: 300,
    alignment: 'center',
    noOpenerFade: true,
                detach: false,
                cloneOnDetach: false
});
```